# Java.lang.NullPointerException on Debug?

Tags: java, eclipse

This is a little bit of my project code:

```
public void render(int[] pixels, int offset, int row) {
      for (int yTile = yOffset <<3; yTile <= (yOffset + height) >>3; yTile++) {
       int yMin = yTile * 8 - yOffset;
       int yMax = yMin + 8;
       if (yMin < 0) yMin = 0;
       if (yMax > height) yMax = height;

       for (int xTile = xOffset <<3; xTile <= (xOffset + width) >>3; xTile++) {
        int xMin = xTile * 8 - xOffset;
        int xMax = xMin + 8;
        if (xMin < 0) xMin = 0;
        if (xMax > width) xMax = width;

        int tileIndex = (xTile &(MAP_WIDTH_MASK)) + (yTile &(MAP_WIDTH_MASK)) * MAP_WIDTH;

        for (int y = yMin; y <yMax; y++) {
         int sheetPixel = ((y + yOffset) & 7) * sheet.width + ((xMin + xOffset) & 7);
         int tilePixel = offset + xMin + y * row;
         for (int x = xMin; x < xMax; x++) {
          int colour = tileIndex * 4 + sheet.pixels[sheetPixel++];
          pixels[tilePixel++] = colours[colour];
         }
        }
      }
     }
 }
}
```

When I run my project, it gives me an error on this line:

```
int colour = tileIndex * 4 + sheet.pixels[sheetPixel++];
```

Can you please tell me how can I can fix this error?

Comment: What's null? sheet? sheet.pixels? Test and see!

Answer (score 0):

In your code, I did not see where `sheet` is defined. 
Try change it

```
int colour = tileIndex * 4 + pixels[sheetPixel++];
```

I assume you are trying to access the value from `int[] pixels` passing as a parameter in the function call.